# How to reuse a regular command line command in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio Code (VSCode) and have a number of command line commands that I use regularly. I find myself typing this in every time I need to use them, but I'm assuming there is some way of calling up previously used commands?

For example, to publish my dotnet app, I run this command:

`dotnet publish -c Release -o ./publish`

Is there some way of adding that as a keyboard shortcut?

What newbie technique am I missing?

Comment: How about `echo dotnet publish -c Release -o ./publish > publish.bat`

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks

Answer (score 0):

You can assign that command to a keybinding like this:

```
{
  "key":  "alt+q",   // choose your keybinding
  "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
  "args": {
    "text": "dotnet publish -c Release -o ./publish",
  }  
}
```

Adding `\u000d` to the end is a return so it runs immediately:

```
    "text": "dotnet publish -c Release -o ./publish\u000d",
```

See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_send-text-from-a-keybinding